# Do link shorteners affect SEO due to the altered anchor text?

Tags: hyperlink, seo, search-engine

I'm curious as to whether or not link shorteners like tinyurl, bitly, etc., affect backlinking in any way.

For instance, the gplus.to link shortener shortens your google+ page.  So that will change your Google+ link anchor from:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/73418324312440134122432433432/posts

to

https://gplus.to/mycompanyname

Is this necessarily a **bad thing** for SEO backlinking purposes?  Will the googlebot not "recognize" the shortened link and will it not aid my SERPS?

I suppose the same goes for everything.  If I shorten a longer link to my company's website by using something like bitly.com ... Does this effectively make it "**not a backlink**", as opposed to if I posted the entire link (http://www.company.com/products/metals/default.aspx)?  Any guidance in this regard would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on URL shortening service, if they are using HTTP 301/302 for redirects, than google will be good with it, however, few search engines also use words from url kinda

```
www.demo.com/how-to-search-better
```

Changes to

```
www.bit.ly/12345
```

Doesn't make sense to search engines or to the user either

Comment: Thank you @Mr. Alien.  That question was bothering me and I couldn't find any help googling for answers.  I suppose you'd have to do some digging to figure out whether the shortener uses a 301 redirect or not, but regardless, I'll stick to the longer URLs now when writing articles, blogging, updating social media sites, etc.  I really do appreciate you taking the time to read my question, respond, and share the knowledge!

Comment: @JasonWeber Actually I had read somewhere, that shortened url are not descriptive, user often bookmarks url or paste in there diaries, using `bit.ly/12345` doesn't make sense but `www.website.com/this-is-a-great-article` does make sense